# Is there a way to continue the current game immediately after launching?

Tags: pc, kingdom-come-deliverance

Many games, especially older ones, had a command line to automatically load the last saved game. I know that Kingdom Come is moddable and has a console, so I was wondering if there's one way or another to set the game so that "Continue" is triggered immediately.

It would be quite helpful, given the long loading times, during which I usually leave the computer while the game is loading.